# reply only pdf / img phpmailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I am trying to make an answer in which I send a pdf, I already tried and everything goes well, but I want the answer (reply) to only get the pdf, and not the data that the form entered.

My question is, is there a possibility that when you answer, only the pdf will arrive without the need to get the data that I enter in the form?

**1- I receive the form data
2- the person who filled out the form receives a pdf / img, but that the data entered in the form does not arrive**

```
<?php

$nombre = $_POST['name'];

$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefono = $_POST['phone'];


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './Exception.php';
require './PHPMailer.php';
require './SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '*****@******';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '*****';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls ';    // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('******@***', 'Página web' );



    $mail->addReplyTo($email);
    $mail->addCC($email);
    $mail->addBCC($email); 

    // Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('atencion-memoria.pdf');
            // Add attachments



$message  = "<html><body>";


$message .= "<table align='center' width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='max-width:650px; background-color:#fff; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'>";



$message .= "<tbody>



<tr style='border-radius:10px'>
    <th style='color:white;background:linear-gradient(50deg,rgb(15,90,224) 0%,rgb(15,90,224) 0%,rgb(116,0,186) 100%,rgb(116,0,186) 100%);text-align:center;padding:10px'>Nombres</th>
    <td style='padding:10px'>
    <p style='font-size:15px;font-family:Century Gothic;margin:2px'>".$nombre."</p>

    </td>

  </tr>


  <tr style='border-radius:10px'>
    <th style='color:white;background:linear-gradient(50deg,rgb(15,90,224) 0%,rgb(15,90,224) 0%,rgb(116,0,186) 100%,rgb(116,0,186) 100%);text-align:center;padding:10px'>Email</th>
    <td style='padding:10px'>
    <p style='font-size:15px;font-family:Century Gothic;margin:2px'>".$email."</p>

    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr style='border-radius:10px'>
    <th style='color:white;background:linear-gradient(50deg,rgb(15,90,224) 0%,rgb(15,90,224) 0%,rgb(116,0,186) 100%,rgb(116,0,186) 100%);text-align:center;padding:10px'>Teléfono</th>
    <td style='padding:10px'>
    <p style='font-size:15px;font-family:Century Gothic;margin:2px'>".$telefono."</p>

    </td>

  </tr>


              </tbody>";

$message .= "</table>";



$message .= "</body></html>";
    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Pagina de Bienestar ';
    $mail->AltBody = 'mensaje alternativo 11';
    $mail->Body    =  $message ;


    $mail->send();
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
    window.location.href = '*****';
    </script>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

Just don't assign form in `$mail->Body = $message;` and you won't add the form to the email:

```
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Pagina de Bienestar ';
$mail->AltBody = 'mensaje alternativo 11';
$mail->Body    =  $message ;

// to
$mail->isHTML(false);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Pagina de Bienestar ';
$mail->Body = 'mensaje alternativo 11';
```

Comment: Thank you, friend, but what I want is for me to receive the information that the person enters in the form on my website, and the person responds by reaching a pdf / img. //

then your solution does not reach me the information on the form :(//

Sorry, I think I did not explain myself well above

Comment: just `echo $message;` to get your form onto the page